# Bluetooth connection error

Tags: arch-linux, bluetooth, bluez, arduino

I want to connect my laptop(Arch Linux) to arduino. I am connecting it via bluez and using hc-05 on the arduino side.

The problem is, bluez is connecting fine with android phone, android phone is connecting fine with hc-05 too, but when trying to connect bluez to hc-05 it never connects.

It pairs successfully, but doesn't connect.
Earlier this morning I was trying to pair and it wasn't pairing but when I tried to connect, it connected!
After a reboot it's opposite now, It pairs but never connects

The error is

```
[bluetooth]# connect 98:D3:31:90:24:76 
Attempting to connect to 98:D3:31:90:24:76
[CHG] Device 98:D3:31:90:24:76 Connected: yes
[CHG] Device 98:D3:31:90:24:76 ServicesResolved: yes
Failed to connect: org.bluez.Error.NotAvailable
[CHG] Device 98:D3:31:90:24:76 ServicesResolved: no
[CHG] Device 98:D3:31:90:24:76 Connected: no
[bluetooth]#
```

The dmesg would be -

```
dmesg | grep luetooth
[    8.424435] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.22
[    8.424453] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[    8.424459] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[    8.424461] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[    8.424467] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[    8.588905] Bluetooth: hci0: rtl: examining hci_ver=06 hci_rev=000b lmp_ver=06 lmp_subver=8723
[    8.588907] Bluetooth: hci0: rtl: loading rtl_bt/rtl8723b_config.bin
[    8.752742] Bluetooth: hci0: rtl: loading rtl_bt/rtl8723b_fw.bin
[    8.765889] Bluetooth: hci0: rom_version status=0 version=1
[    8.765911] Bluetooth: cfg_sz 44, total size 22540
[   11.659685] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[   11.659687] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[   11.659692] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
[ 1150.278244] Bluetooth: RFCOMM TTY layer initialized
[ 1150.278253] Bluetooth: RFCOMM socket layer initialized
[ 1150.278275] Bluetooth: RFCOMM ver 1.11
[ 2967.008290] Bluetooth: hci0 urb ffff88013e088600 failed to resubmit (2)
[ 3644.900996] Bluetooth: hci0: rtl: examining hci_ver=06 hci_rev=0e2f lmp_ver=06 lmp_subver=9f73
[ 3644.900998] Bluetooth: rtl: assuming no firmware upload needed.
[ 5274.608968] Bluetooth: hci0: rtl: examining hci_ver=06 hci_rev=000b lmp_ver=06 lmp_subver=8723
[ 5274.608970] Bluetooth: hci0: rtl: loading rtl_bt/rtl8723b_config.bin
[ 5274.609003] Bluetooth: hci0: rtl: loading rtl_bt/rtl8723b_fw.bin
[ 5274.609950] Bluetooth: hci0: rom_version status=0 version=1
[ 5274.609964] Bluetooth: cfg_sz 44, total size 22540
[root@Turing ~]# dmesg | grep luetooth
[    8.424435] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.22
[    8.424453] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[    8.424459] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[    8.424461] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[    8.424467] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[    8.588905] Bluetooth: hci0: rtl: examining hci_ver=06 hci_rev=000b lmp_ver=06 lmp_subver=8723
[    8.588907] Bluetooth: hci0: rtl: loading rtl_bt/rtl8723b_config.bin
[    8.752742] Bluetooth: hci0: rtl: loading rtl_bt/rtl8723b_fw.bin
[    8.765889] Bluetooth: hci0: rom_version status=0 version=1
[    8.765911] Bluetooth: cfg_sz 44, total size 22540
[   11.659685] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[   11.659687] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[   11.659692] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
[ 1150.278244] Bluetooth: RFCOMM TTY layer initialized
[ 1150.278253] Bluetooth: RFCOMM socket layer initialized
[ 1150.278275] Bluetooth: RFCOMM ver 1.11
[ 2967.008290] Bluetooth: hci0 urb ffff88013e088600 failed to resubmit (2)
[ 3644.900996] Bluetooth: hci0: rtl: examining hci_ver=06 hci_rev=0e2f lmp_ver=06 lmp_subver=9f73
[ 3644.900998] Bluetooth: rtl: assuming no firmware upload needed.
[ 5274.608968] Bluetooth: hci0: rtl: examining hci_ver=06 hci_rev=000b lmp_ver=06 lmp_subver=8723
[ 5274.608970] Bluetooth: hci0: rtl: loading rtl_bt/rtl8723b_config.bin
[ 5274.609003] Bluetooth: hci0: rtl: loading rtl_bt/rtl8723b_fw.bin
[ 5274.609950] Bluetooth: hci0: rom_version status=0 version=1
[ 5274.609964] Bluetooth: cfg_sz 44, total size 22540
```